# Share to Instagram functionality on Android

Tags: android, android-intent, instagram

From what I've seen, the only way to share pictures on Instagram is through Intents.

> At this time, uploading via the API is not possible. We made a
>   conscious choice not to add this for the following reasons:
>        Instagram is about your life on the go – we hope to encourage photos from within the app. We want to fight spam & low quality
>   photos. Once we allow uploading from other sources, it's harder to
>   control what comes into the Instagram ecosystem. All this being said,
>   we're working on ways to ensure users have a consistent and
>   high-quality experience on our platform.

The only problem is that after uploading the pic, you don't get back in your application and this is not really user friendly, unless back button is pressed or you switch back to your App. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no, there is no way for you to control the app behavior after the sharing was completed. Instagram provides the opportunity to 'send' the image to their app via intents and they don't give you any chance to control this process (at least for now).

Comment: That's what I thought as well :) Didn't hurt asking, thank you.